# Cannot deploy Application to Jetty ServletContainer in Jersey 2.X

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

In Jetty 1.X, it was possible to deploy a `ServletContainer` to jetty using something like:

```
Application application = ...
server.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(application)), "/foo);
```

In Jersey 2.X, the `ServletContainer` class expects a `ResourceConfig` which is a subclass of `Application`. However, the former is part of Jersey implementation whereas the latter is part of JAX-RS specification, meaning that deployment to Jetty now depends on Jersey internal which is something I would like to avoid.

Did I miss something in my migration from Jersey 1 to Jersey 2?

Comment: Why not just add the servlet by class reference instead of object instance?  (that's how `WEB-INF/web.xml` works, and Jersey must support that)

Comment: I want to add specific instances, not a class, because I want to have fine control over how the objects are constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html) is also Jersey specific. Anyways you can create `ResourceConfig` directly from JAX-RS Application using [ResourceConfig#forApplication](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#forApplication%28javax.ws.rs.core.Application%29) or [ResourceConfig#forApplicationClass](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#forApplicationClass%28java.lang.Class%29). Then your code would look like:

```java
server.addServlet( new ServletHolder(
                   new ServletContainer(
                       ResourceConfig.forApplication(application)))
                   , "/foo");
```

Comment: My goal is to avoid dependency on ResourceConfig altogether, because ResourceConfig is a Jersey-specific class. Using your solution would not remove that dependency.

Comment: I understood what you were trying to say. My point was that `ServletContainer` is Jersey-specific as well and using `ResourceConfig` was more convenient. Feel free to create a pull request (https://github.com/jersey/jersey, better way) or file an improvement (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY) if you want to use `Application` directly.

Comment: Apologies for my dumbness, you are perfectly right as that solves my problem: The interface implemented by the server to which the Application is deployed can depend only on JAX-RS while the Jetty/Jersey implementation can rely on Jersey specific stuff.